# Efficient spatial joining for large dataset in r

Tags: r, join, size, spatial, shapefile

I am working with rather large data.frames that i often need to do spatial join on. The fastest way I have come up with so far is this method:

```
library(rgdal)

download.file("http://gis.ices.dk/shapefiles/ICES_ecoregions.zip",
              destfile = "ICES_ecoregions.zip")
unzip("ICES_ecoregions.zip")

# read eco region shapefiles
ices_eco <- rgdal::readOGR(".", "ICES_ecoregions_20150113_no_land", verbose = FALSE)
## Make a large data.frame (361,722 rows) with positions in the North Sea:
lon <- seq(-18.025, 32.025, by=0.05)
lat <- seq(48.025, 66.025, by=0.05)
grd <- expand.grid(lon=lon, lat=lat)

# Get the Ecoregion for each position
pings  <- SpatialPoints(c[c('lon','lat')],proj4string=ices_eco@proj4string)
grd$area   <- over(pings,ices_eco)$Ecoregion
```

But this takes a very long time and uses a lot of RAM, and will sometime come up with the Error: cannot allocate vector of size 460 Kb (if you cant reproduce the error, just make c larger). Anyone can come up with a better/faster/more efficient solution?

Comment: what's `c`, and are you doing something with the `expand.grid`? It's not recommended to call a variable `c`, given that it's also a function.